# Create co-occurence list from JSON file

Tags: python, json

Trying to match actors who have been in the same movie together, and put them into a list with each element being a pair of actors.

This is the basic outline of the JSON file:

```
[
    {
        "id": "1234567",
        "name": "Dwayne Johnson",
        "born": "1970-12-12",
        "movies": [
            {
                "id": "345678",
                "title": "Fast and furious 7",
                "role": "actor",
                "year": 2017,
                "kind": "movie"
            },
            {
                "id": "345678",
                "title": "blah blah",
                "role": "actor",
                "year": 2020,
                "kind": "movie"
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "7844682",
        "name": "Nicole Kidman",
        "born": "1970-12-12",
        "movies": [
            {
                "id": "10161886",
                "title": "The Prom",
                "role": "actress",
                "year": 2020,
                "kind": "movie"
            },
            {
                "id": "345678",
                "title": "blah blah",
                "role": "actress",
                "year": 2020,
                "kind": "movie"
            },
```

etc. etc. for about 70,000 lines. My desired output looks like

```
[ ('Dwayne Johnson', 'Nicole Kidman'), ('Dwayne Johnson', 'Jason Statham') ...... etc. ]
```

So Dwayne Johnson and Nicole Kidman were both in 'blah blah', therefore they make a pair.

I've gone through several attempts, but all I really have to show for it is this

```
import json, itertools

fin = open("actors.json","r")
data = json.load(fin)
fin.close()

for actor in data:
        actor_pairs = list( itertools.combinations(actor["name"], r=2))
print(actor_pairs)
```

But this just prints out every combination of letters of the last actor in the files name.

```
[ ('N', 'i'), ('N', 'c')....etc. ]
```

I'm at a bit of a loss, and unsure what to do. Do I need some more nested for loops, or something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the below, really non-performant code with the data set you provided above and it seems to be working.

I can improve it for it's efficiency but can you test this code out for the whole set of data you have.

```
data = [
    {
        "id": "1234567",
        "name": "Dwayne Johnson",
        "born": "1970-12-12",
        "movies": [
            {
                "id": "345678",
                "title": "Fast and furious 7",
                "role": "actor",
                "year": 2017,
                "kind": "movie"
            },
            {
                "id": "345678",
                "title": "blah blah",
                "role": "actor",
                "year": 2020,
                "kind": "movie"
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "7844682",
        "name": "Nicole Kidman",
        "born": "1970-12-12",
        "movies": [
            {
                "id": "10161886",
                "title": "The Prom",
                "role": "actress",
                "year": 2020,
                "kind": "movie"
            },
            {
                "id": "345678",
                "title": "blah blah",
                "role": "actress",
                "year": 2020,
                "kind": "movie"
            }
        ]

    }
]
movie_actor_list = []
for d in data:
    for movie in d['movies']:
        movie_actor_list.append((d['name'], movie['title']))

final_list = []
for name1, movie1 in movie_actor_list:
    for name2, movie2 in movie_actor_list:
        if movie1 == movie2 and not name1 == name2 and not (name2, name1) in final_list:
            final_list.append((name1, name2))

print(final_list)
```

Output :

```
[('Dwayne Johnson', 'Nicole Kidman')]
```

Comment: I don't think `name` or `title` are unique keys, and shouldn't be used as such.

Comment: @Jon  I'm not using them as keys, They are tuples.

Comment: right, but it is made of non-unique values. The `actor` and `movie` dicts have an `id` key that appears to be unique. Instead of `movie_actor_list.append((d['name'], movie['title']))` it should be `movie_actor_list.append((d['id'], movie['id']))`

Comment: Thank you so much, it works great. The non-unique values part doesn't really matter for my situation as the number of times they appear as a pair will be important later on.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative one-line solution would be:

```
actor_pairs = [(actor1, actor2) for (actor1, movies1), (actor2, movies2) in itertools.combinations([(actor['name'], {movie['id'] for movie in actor['movies']}) for actor in data], r=2) if len(movies1 & movies2) > 0]
```

The solution broken down to steps:

```
# create a list of tuples where each tuple contains the actor's name and a set of the ids from all the movies they worked on 
actors_and_movies = [(actor['name'], {movie['id'] for movie in actor['movies']}) for actor in data]
# Create all combinations of the previous list
all_combinations = itertools.combinations(actors_and_movies, r=2)
# Create a list of tuples containing 2 actors if the intersection between their movies is not empty
actor_pairs = [(actor1, actor2) for (actor1, movies1), (actor2, movies2) in all_combinations if movies1 & movies2]
```

Comment: Thank you, I ended up adapting my own code to include both yours and Gauri's. Your help is greatly appreciated :)